# Unknown column ' ' in 'where clause

Tags: php, sql, database, drop-down-menu

I have been scouring the stack-overflow site and tried most of the similar questions that had been asked/answered, but unfortunately none of the solutions have worked for me so far. I am trying to have a list that is being populated by an sql database (which is working) and then once selecting the item, hitting the "generate" button and grabbing the data from the table and posting ONLY the selected data into the table. Previously I had an issue where the tables where being populated with ALL the data from the weapons list. After working on it some I have am now getting the error "Unknown column (whichever weapon name I choose) in where clause 107 (which I am assuming is my line number). Any suggestions?

Here is the entirety of the form from populating the list from the database to trying to select the weapon from the list.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            Martial Weapon Name
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <select name="Choosen">
                    <?php 
                    echo'<option>Select Weapon</option>';
                    //Check if at least one row is found
                    if($result->num_rows >0){
                        //Loop through results
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            //Display weapon info
                            $output = $row['weapon_name'];
                            echo '<option>'.$output.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate">
    <h3>
        Weapon
    </h3>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Weapon Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Weapon Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Damage
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $selected_weapon = $_POST['Choosen'];
            $choose = "SELECT
            weapon_types_martial.id,
            weapon_types_martial.weapon_name,
            weapon_types_martial.weapon_type,
            weapon_types_martial.weapon_damage 
            FROM weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_types_martial.weapon_name = " . $selected_weapon;
            $result = $mysqli->query($choose) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
            foreach ($result->fetch_assoc() as $item) {
                //Display weapon
                $show = '<tr>';
                $show .= '<td>' . $item['weapon_name'] . '</td>';
                $show .= '<td>' . $item['weapon_type'] . '</td>';
                $show .= '<td>' . $item['weapon_damage'] . '</td>';
                $show .= '</tr>';
                //Echo output
                echo $show;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

And lastly here is the screenshot of what I am getting

[image: Clause Error]

Comment: it seems `$_POST['choosen']` have no value  so check that. And change like this:-`FROM weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_types_martial.weapon_name =$selected_weapon;"`

Comment: Thank you so far everyone. I am starting to go through these to see what I can find. I am still really new to sql so some of this is a bit difficult for me to comb through, but I am trying. @Anant I am working through yours now and it did not work, but a new error is showing up. I am trying to look through real quick before I post the result to it. (Essentially it is saying Choosen is an unidentified index immediately before I even query anything.)

Comment: @Anant When I pasted your code exactly I was getting error [index](http://imgur.com/YAyuzEn)

Comment: @Leo check my answer below may be your issue solve

Comment: Please don't add "Thanks", "[solved]" or an answer into your question**s**. If you have accepted an answer everybody knows that the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)You will not get data in $_POST['choosen'] As you haven't pass value in dropdown(select)**

**2)In your database table may be field `weapon_name` is varchar so you have to pass it into single quote.**

Change your code as below:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            Martial Weapon Name
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <select name="Choosen">
                    <?php 
                    echo '<option>Select Weapon</option>';
                    //Check if at least one row is found
                    if($result->num_rows >0){
                        //Loop through results
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            //Display weapon info
                            $output = $row['weapon_name'];
                            echo '<option value="'.$output.'">'.$output.'</option>';  //<--------------change here
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate">
    <h3>
        Weapon
    </h3>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Weapon Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Weapon Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Damage
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $selected_weapon = $_POST['Choosen'];
            $choose = "SELECT
            id,
            weapon_name,
            weapon_type,
            weapon_damage 
            FROM weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_name = '$selected_weapon'"; //<--------------change here
            $result = $mysqli->query($choose) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //Display weapon
                $show = '<tr>';
                $show .= '<td>' . $item['weapon_name'] . '</td>';
                $show .= '<td>' . $item['weapon_type'] . '</td>';
                $show .= '<td>' . $item['weapon_damage'] . '</td>';
                $show .= '</tr>';
                //Echo output
                echo $show;
            }
           }
           else
          {
             echo "No data found";
          }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Trying this I received a new error, 118-119 lines are all the `$show = '<tr>';` for the weapon_name, type and damage. [new error](http://imgur.com/ajzlC22)

Comment: Ok so your query executed success. Check my edited answer I have removed `weapon_types_martial.` from query.@Leo

Comment: Still the same results. Getting the `Warning: Illegal string offset 'weapon_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\apptest\weapons.php on line 117` , `type` and all the way through the whole table, just like the image I posted above.

Comment: @Leo. Will you `var_dump($item)` after `foreach ($result->fetch_assoc() as $item) {` and tell whats the output

Comment: @Leo see my edited answer I have added one condition when no data found from query

Comment: I am really sorry, I am not sure I understand. Do I just post the `var_dump` within the `foreach ()` or just as you show right after the `{ ` Because it's only giving me an error page when I do it after the { but it says `unexpected $show`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136521/discussion-between-b-desai-and-leo).

Answer (score 1):

You need to place quotes in your SQL query.
Try:

```
$choose = "SELECT
  weapon_types_martial.id,
  weapon_types_martial.weapon_name,
  weapon_types_martial.weapon_type,
  weapon_types_martial.weapon_damage 
  FROM weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_types_martial.weapon_name = '" . $selected_weapon . "'";
```

Word of advice, this query is very unsafe. I suggest using a framework or library for database queries.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but as I am still very new to SQL can you link some documentation on the framework or library stuff? I am not exactly sure what you mean by it not being safe but know this isn't the place for general questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give value inside single quotes,

```
$choose = "SELECT
  weapon_types_martial.id,
  weapon_types_martial.weapon_name,
  weapon_types_martial.weapon_type,
  weapon_types_martial.weapon_damage 
  FROM weapon_types_martial
  WHERE weapon_types_martial.weapon_name = '" . $selected_weapon ."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$choose = "SELECT id, weapon_name, weapon_type, weapon_damage FROM weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_name = '".$selected_weapon."'";
```

or

```
$choose = "SELECT weapon_types_martial.id, weapon_types_martial.weapon_name, weapon_types_martial.weapon_type, weapon_types_martial.weapon_damage  FROM weapon_types_martial as weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_types_martial.weapon_name = '" . $selected_weapon ."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `options` in your select element don't have a `value=..` attribute, meaning that nothing is present in your query.

So `$_POST['Choosen']` will = `''`.

Not to mention that you're trying to pass a string, so your query will need to be wrapped in `'`:

```
$choose = "SELECT id, weapon_name, weapon_type, weapon_damage FROM weapon_types_martial WHERE weapon_name = '".$selected_weapon."'";
```